# Enable external network access from my docker swarm

Tags: networking, docker, devops, swarm, devops-services

I have a docker swarm running in my environment. Each service instance can see the others instances, so far, so good. The problem is that this services should access a database witch is in a DMZ (and I'm not having too much success in this).

So, I have the docker swarm running with an overlay network, is there any modification I can do to enable this services to reach the external database? Today I'm getting this exception:  "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure
that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

My service creation:

```
sudo docker service create --name myimage_swarm --network=myoverlaynetworkwithscopeswarm --mount ... -p 9091:8080 myimage
```

My networks

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
7a840b9be53e        bridge              bridge              local
d2752a80d7e8        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
1oherstrwm3y        myoverlaynetworkwithscopeswarm overlay             swarm
e975164865ba        host                host                local
7a4j98xz6w2s        ingress             overlay             swarm
3811761c92ed        none                null                local
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I've find out the problem, thats nothing about docker, but my dockerfile. I was using centos, but without the net-utils package, so, docker cant create the others networks. After adding the package, the network interfaces (internal and external) get created.